# Git tries to lstat files outside its work directory

Tags: git, mingw32

I recently started experiencing weird behavior with git. I'm on Windows 7 and using MINGW32.

My git repository is in `/d/www/project1/app`

When I type in `git pull origin master`, I used to get:

```
fatal: cannot lstat '\/$RECYCLE.BIN': No such file or directory
```

Which is a hidden system folder in `/d`. After removing it, I noticed it just moved on to the next file it could find in `/d` (root folder of my D: drive) and is still throwing the same lstat error.

So the question is simple - why on earth does it try to lstat every file and folder on my D drive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a `.git` folder ( created accidentally maybe) in the root of drive D: ( and you are not doing the command in the correct folder where your actual repo)

Comment: There isn't. And I'm doing the command in the correct folder. I've been working on that project (and that repo) for almost a year now and it always worked fine. I get the same error even if I try to clone it to a new folder. All the other repos seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Note that with Git 2.5+ (Q2 2015), this error message should not pop up anymore.

See [commit 838d6a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/838d6a928fc3aef3827d9a45e6aac044fea7451e) by [David Turner (`csusbdt`)](https://github.com/csusbdt), 18 May 2015.
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f93a393](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f93a3937877386af5d870b68db20d2ff27e3e41e), 01 Jun 2015)</sup>

> ### `clean`: only `lstat` files in `pathspec`
>
> Even though ["git clean"](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) takes `pathspec` to limit the part of the working tree to be cleaned, it checked the paths it encounters during its directory traversal with [`lstat(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat), before checking if the path is within the pathspec.
>
> **Ignore paths outside pathspec** and proceed without checking with
>   [`lstat(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat).  Even if such a path is unreadable due to e.g. `EPERM`,
>   ["`git clean`"](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) should not care.

And with [git-for-windows releases](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), a Git for Windows will be only days after the Linux Git release itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where my local gitlab runner stored builds on an ExFat formatted external hard drive. After formatting it to Mac OS Extended Journaled, it worked